# "Reliable in/at/for V-ing" Which is grammatically correct?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

For example, is any of the following sentences correct?

- He's always a reliable husband **in** providing both moral and financial support for her projects.
- He's always a reliable husband **for** providing both moral and financial support for her projects.
- He's always a reliable husband **at** providing both moral and financial support for her projects.

Comment: I think all of these are a little clunky/awkward to be honest, but this has nothing to do with grammar.  I would prefer "when it comes to providing", remove "her", and then it should be "**for** her projects".  It's not logical to provide mental support **to** her projects, because a project doesn't have a brain.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A Hi! You edited the question very well. Now it looks better.

Comment: I partially agree with Billy Kerr's comment above, by "mental support" do you mean *encouragement*  i.e. "**in providing encouragement** *and  financial support **for** her projects*" or *emotional support* as in: "*in providing financial **and emotional support** for her projects*"

Comment: How do you define a 'reliable husband'? I would prefer **Her husband can always be relied on to provide her with both financial and psychological support for her projects**.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - yes "encouragement" or "emotional support" would be be better.  "Mental support" sounds like something a psychiatrist would provide.

Comment: I'd be inclined to make the second part a participle phrase: "He's always **been** a reliable husband, providing her **with** both financial and mental support **for** her projects"... unless, of course, he has been reliable only in these two ways...

Comment: @BillyKerr you're right, and it's a shrewd observation for the brain part :)) (at least, to be)!

Comment: He is always a husband who is reliable at providing x or as Kate says. The error is starting with "reliable husband".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - He's always a reliable husband **in** providing her both financial and mental support to her projects.
> - He's always a reliable husband **for** providing her both financial and mental support to her projects.
> - He's always a reliable husband **at** providing her both financial and mental support to her projects.

All the above sentences are, technically, grammatically correct, but a native speaker of English is unlikely to use those sentences.The meanings of those sentences are unclear, and they are not idiomatic.

A native speaker of English is more likely to use the following sentence:

> Her husband can always be relied on to provide her with both financial and psychological support for her projects.

The meaning of that sentence is clear and the sentence is natural.

Comment: [This Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=reliable+in%2C+reliable+for%2C+reliable+at%2C+reliable+on&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) shows that 'in' is the most common and 'on' much the least - and in many examples 'on' is part of another phrase such as 'on that occasion'.

Comment: The last part needs to be either "providing her both financial and mental support for her projects" or "providing both financial and mental support to her projects". The support is either to her  (for her projects) or to her projects.

Comment: "He's always a reliable husband AT providing her both financial and mental support to her projects." feels very wrong, clunky at best. "He's always reliable AT providing her both financial and mental support to her projects." would be not incorrect but still a bit odd.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Hi! Thank you very much for your comment! It's very useful! I edited again my answer and I have included it in it. Do you like my answer now?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't like it very much. All the versions may be 'grammatically correct', but none is particularly idiomatic, least of all your version with _on_.

Comment: @KateBunting Hi! I edited again my answer. Do you like it now?

Comment: I've edited it to make your English more idiomatic.

Comment: @KateBunting Hi! Thank you very much for editing my answer and your help! Now it looks better!

Answer (score -1):

All three are grammatically correct. However, none are natural, their meanings are unclear, and to the extent they're clear, they're slightly different.

The meaning of your first sentence, with "in", is the most difficult to understand. "In" has many different meanings as a preposition, and it's difficult to determine which one is intended here.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in) has these possible meanings:

> **in** *preposition*
> **3 a —>** used as a function word to indicate limitation, qualification, or circumstance
> *alike in some respects
>
> left in a hurry*

So this sentence could mean:

- he was a reliable husband *only* in terms of providing her that support, perhaps implying he was less reliable in other ways (*limitation*); OR
- he was a reliable husband *because* he provided her that support (*qualification*)

Your second sentence, with "for", roughly means:

> He's a reliable husband **due to the fact that** he provides...

In other words, it *defines* a husband who does those things as "reliable".

The meaning of your third sentence, with "at", means he reliably provides those things to her. The word "husband" doesn't add anything, other than to perhaps inform the reader that he's her husband. It reads better without it:

> He's always reliable at providing...

Comment: i think reliable husband for, in or at are all three wrong.

Comment: @Lambie They certainly sound bad and have little semantic value. Do you mean they're grammatically incorrect too? Can you say more?

Comment: For me, if a thing sounds bad, it is not grammatical. I would never write any of those. The issue arises mostly from using "reliable husband" at the beginning.